# SQL Server subscription that can work without the publisher

Tags: sql-server, replication

My requirement is to have a SQL Server replicated on another server and even if the publisher server is shut down unexpectedly the subscriber should have all the information and can be used without being connected to the publisher.

I was able to create the replication and when the publisher is alive all data are accessible from the subscriber but once I stop the publisher the subscriber is entering the recovery mode and becomes inaccessible.

I know that I might need to implement HA solutions but can't it be done without that?

Comment: If stopping the "publisher" causes the "subscriber" to go offline, it sounds like you have either mirroring or an availability group set up. What command(s) did you use to set up "replication"?

Comment: It’s a transactional replication. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/transactional/transactional-replication?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: It's not normal for the Subscriber database to be inaccessible (or go into Recovery Mode) when the Publisher in a Replication topology goes offline. You should still be able to access the Subscriber database. So something is really wrong with your database servers or how they're configured. "*I stop the publisher*" - How are you doing this? Do you see any corruption (though I have a feeling not) if you run [`DBCC CHECKDB`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkdb-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) on either the Publisher or Subscriber database?

Comment: And so what kind of replication is this?